# Retornando dados do CEP em formulário

Tags: html, python, angularjs, django

To com o seguinte problema: estou tentanto preencher os campos
logradouro, cidade e estado com o cep informado.
São todos input.
Estou usando https://github.com/jbochi/cep
Meu projeto é em Django, mas eu acho que dá pra retornar os dados diretamente na página html (front-end), visto que é só preenchimento e inserção.

Como eu faço isso? Tentei com AngularJS, mas estou apanhando.

Me ajudem por favor.

Comment: Olá @Regis. Como está o código que fez? Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, e para poder te ajudar, é necessário um [Exemplo Mínimo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Regis poste o seu código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Vc precisa de alguma url no seu backend que aceite um cep e devolva u json.
Ou seja, vc vai abrir no seu browser: `localhost:8000/api/consultacep/91370000` e vai ver:

`{'Localidade': u'Porto Alegre', 'Bairro': u'Vila Ipiranga', 'UF': u'RS', 'Logradouro': u'Rua Alberto Silva - at\xe9 965/966', 'CEP': u'91370-000'}`

2) Em algum lugar no seu controller vc vai fazer uma chamada pra essa api e salvar o resultado no $scope:

`$http.get('/api/consultacep/91370000').success(function(local){
    $scope.local_encontrado = local;
});`

3) No seu template vc precisa mostrar os atributos de $scope.local_encontrado. Faça isso usando ng-model:

`Localidade: <input type="text" ng-model="local_encontrado.Localidade"><br>
Bairro: <input type="text" ng-model="local_encontrado.Bairro"><br>
UF: <input type="text" ng-model="local_encontrado.UF"><br>
<!-- etc -->`

Answer (score 1):

Meu amigo @Tony Lâmpada me deu mais uma ajudinha!

Thanks @Tony Lâmpada

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('app', []);
    angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($http, $scope){

        $scope.busca = function(){
            $http.get('http://api.postmon.com.br/cep/'+ $scope.cep).success(function(local){
                $scope.local_encontrado = local;
                console.log(local);
            });
        };

        $scope.enter = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                $scope.busca();
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```