# Tratando erro quando não retorna dados (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs

A partir da pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97757/761 como eu faço para tratar o erro quando não encontra o CEP?

Vejam o erro que ele retorna, eu queria que retornasse um alerta quando der esse erro:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.postmon.com.br/cep/053140010. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: voce esta solicitando o cep atraves do proprio js? ou esta usando php ou outro metodo? consegue mostrar o codigo que faz a chamada?

Comment: Poderia fornecer o trecho de código angular que contem a consulta?

Comment: Pode editar com o seu código? Irei fazer uma resposta utilizando o exemplo do cara como pode ser feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Código da resposta que você mencionou como referência**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('app', []);
    angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($http, $scope){

        $scope.busca = function(){
            $http.get('http://api.postmon.com.br/cep/'+ $scope.cep).success(function(local){
                $scope.local_encontrado = local;
                console.log(local);
            });
        };

        $scope.enter = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                $scope.busca();
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```

Repare que o exemplo utiliza apenas o método `success`, ou seja, quando não retorna nenhum erro e o status da resposta é `2**`, geralmente `200`. Então, o que falta? Falta mencionar outro método chamado `error`, com a intenção de tratar quando ocorre determinado erro, como esse que você mencionou, veja como fica o código:

**Alteração do código tratando os erros**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('app', []);
    angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($http, $scope){

        $scope.busca = function(){
            $http.get('http://api.postmon.com.br/cep/'+ $scope.cep)
            .success(function(local){
                $scope.local_encontrado = local;
                console.log(local);
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                alert("Erro ao carregar CEP");
            });
        };

        $scope.enter = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13){
                $scope.busca();
            };
        };
    });
</script>
```

No corpo do código inseri a função `error` para que quando ocorrer determinado erro mostrar um alert para o usuário saber o que aconteceu, normalmente irá ser chamado esse método quando um status de uma resposta HTTP for `4**` ou `5**`.

Isso vai tratar os erros como o erro que você mencionou, porém se não encontrar determinado CEP consulte a documentação da API que você esta utilizando para verificar o seu retorno. Mesmo não encontrando o CEP, vai cair dentro de `success` para tratar essa informação, não vai cair dentro de `error` porque foi uma requisição bem sucedida, certo?

**Referências**:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html